# Install Cray's gdb4hpc on a personal Linux computer

Tags: debugging, gdb, mpi, cray

Is there a way to install Cray's `gdb4hpc` on a personal Linux computer? I want to debug MPI applications on my local computer.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you with cray products. But try: `mpiexec -n 4 xterm -e gdb yourprogram`. That's a very low budget debugger.

Comment: Or try [tmpi](https://github.com/Azrael3000/tmpi)